# Xposed Log not working after adding check for package name

Tags: android, logging, xposed

So I have this class for an Xposed module which I wrote following this tutorial [Xposed module tutorial](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial). The first snippet of code from the tutorial works just fine:

```
public class MyClass implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
    }
}
```

The log gets printed for every app that gets opened on the device.
However when proceeding to the next example that shows how to select only the package that you are interested in

```
public void handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.mypackage"))
    return;

XposedBridge.log("we are in mypackage!");}
```

nothing gets printed in the logs. So I even tried keeping the log from the first example in case something was wrong with my package specifically and the code looked like this:

```
public void handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);

if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.mypackage"))
    return;

XposedBridge.log("we are in mypackage!");}
```

yet no packages were printed. After completely removing the `if` the logs start showing up again so it seems that adding that check is the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By any chance, had you solved this problem? The only explanation I can figure out would be that `lpparam.packageName` is null (which shouldn't be encountered) so an NPE occurs at the `.equals()`, but even in that case, you would have had "Loaded app: null" log entries from the code above…

Comment: Though, `lpparam` cannot be null, I have verified in the [code of Xposed](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/a535c02ed9dfd53683cc0274d9f95bcb6ffb9f79/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/callbacks/XC_LoadPackage.java#L60-L61). Also search for `reportedPackageName` in [beforeHookedMethod](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/a535c02ed9dfd53683cc0274d9f95bcb6ffb9f79/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedInit.java#L108), it cannot be null, otherwise errors would happen before reaching your code. So I think there was some overlook in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `lpparam.packageName` is the package name of the application being hooked. Package names are like unique identifiers for apps. So if you match it against `com.mypackage` and you see no logs, it basically means there are no apps with that package name.

Try the following:

```
if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.mypackage")){
    XposedBridge.log("We are not hooking " + lpparam.packageName + "!");
    return; // Apps with different package names dont get hooks cause you return here
}
```

For example, imagine you wanted to hook the facebook app, then you should compare against `com.facebook.katana`: `!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")`

Comment: You may be right in some part, but I think his/her problem happens before package comparison .

Comment: Did you confirm that your xposed module gets loaded? Can you try it using the default android's logger instead? I haven't checked how Xposed implements its logger but might be that its getting killed before it outputs your message.